# Error when executing memcpy command - Second argument

Tags: c++, sqlite

Can someone help me on this **memcpy** syntax. I suppose in const void* test, there is an error which i am not able to interpret due to code crash at runtime.

```
struct tHistoryRow 
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> blob;
    … … …
};

tHistoryRow tempHistoryRow;
unsigned int valueBlobSize = sqlite3_column_bytes(pStmt, SQLITE_HISTORYDB_INDEX_VALUE);
unsigned ssize = tempHistoryRow.blob.size();
tempHistoryRow.blob.resize(ssize + valueBlobSize);
const void * test =  sqlite3_column_blob(pStmt, SQLITE_HISTORYDB_INDEX_VALUE);
std::memcpy(&tempHistoryRow.blob[ssize - valueBlobSize], test, valueBlobSize);
```

The above code is for your reference.

Thanks rG

Comment: Why not consulting the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)?

Comment: Code crash in a runtime means your syntax is OK, but likely having some memory violation

Comment: `&tempHistoryRow.blob[ssize - valueBlobSize]` looks like your computing a negative index which wraps around to a very large index.  Looks like what you really need is the `data` member function from `std::vector`.

Comment: `std::memcpy(&tempHistoryRow.blob[ssize - valueBlobSize], test, valueBlobSize);` - I might be taking a wild stab in the dark, but shouldn't that be `[ssize]` since you've not yet updated it with the new blob data?

Comment: @NathanOliver @ Chris Turner Not getting what you mean. Please explain a little bit more. Thanks

Comment: @RaunakGupta Do `std::cout << (ssize - valueBlobSize);`.  What value do you get?

Comment: Yes you are right, removing valueBlobSize works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From a logical point of view, the index should be

```
std::memcpy(&tempHistoryRow.blob[ssize], test, valueBlobSize);
```

since I assume, that you want to append data to the vector object.